# How to use Scroller in ViewGroup (android)

Tags: android, scroller, viewgroup

I have a custom ViewGroup and would like to add scrolling ability to it.

Is it possible to use a Scroller object and link it up with view group?

I have read somewhere that Scroller does not do any actual scrolling. That means it must be delegating the scrolling responsibility back to ViewGroup.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) object is what allows for scrolling.  Basically, most Views are able to be scrolled, but they have no way of propagating touch events to the View class.  A `ScrollView` handles this for the user, so should be wrapped around a View whenever you would like to enable Scrolling for a that view.

Remember that a ScrollView can only have one child view, so if you need have multiple views in the same scrolling layout, you'll need to have them all inside one `LinearLayout` (or `RelativeLayout`, or whatever you decide).

Comment: I am trying to build custom viewgroup with its own layout (something like a flowlayout).With that in mind, I am not sure if scrollview is a good idea.Scrollview only provide vertical scrolling, I need horizontal scrolling too. I am not sure how would it impact the onMeasure and onLayout that I have implemented for my view, i.e when somebody scrolls the window/view would I be able to know which children to add to my viewgroup and which to remove?

Comment: You can always wrap the scrollview with a horizontalScrollView.  That would provide scrolling in both the vertical and horizontal directions.  A ScrollView will not have a definite measure though, they are infinite if the View they are wrapping is infinite, I'm not sure how this would affect your ViewGroup.  You'll need to provide more information if this doesn't help, I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish.