# Android: How to scroll the Extended adapterview or viewgroup

Tags: android, listview, adapter, viewgroup, scroller

Following up this [Extending AdapterView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563897/extending-adapterview)

I know this can be achieved by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796960/how-to-use-scroller-in-viewgroup-android)

PLEASE NOTE: Trying to understand the how listview and Gallery scrolls & reuses the view.

How to scroll the Custom ViewGroup/AdapterView?

On going through source code of listview, found that overriding the onTouch() & dispatchTouchEvent() it is possible. (Inferred FlingRunnable keeps on updates the constant using [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) class)

But What is the exact API method to redraw entire view with scrolled offset as smooth as listview/gridview or gallery?

Comment: Can you please suggest if you have found out something by this time?

Comment: @AnithaManikandan I didn't get solution for this

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Mani. Im also facing the same issue.  My custom adapter view is not scrolling as smooth as ListView.

Comment: @AnithaManikandan: If you can share your code on git or here, I would be able to help. With recycler view, I'm able to achieve whatever I want. When I asked this question, Recyclerview was not there.